# Clarification regarding promises and async/await needed

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I have been using `Promises` and `async/await`, they are pretty much the same thing right? Usually what I would do is wrap my promise and return it etc.

```
function someFetchThatTakesTime(){
    // Promisify the request.
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if(allGood){
            resolve();
        }else{
            reject();
    });
}
```

Then I can do:

```
someFetchThatTakesTime()
    .then(console.log('all good.')
    .catch(console.log('some error occured.');
```

or I can do the:

```
async function wrapMyFetch() {
    try {
        // Make the async call.
        data = await someFetchThatTakesTime();
        return data;
    } catch(err) {
        // Propagate the exception up stream.
        throw err;
    }
}

(async () => {
  let response = await wrapMyFetch();
  // Do stuff with the response.
})();
```

I guess, pretty clear so far.

However, I have recently encountered situations where my application does not care about waiting for the results to be fetched and the data containers to be updated etc. Let's say there is one larger loop that runs infinitely and any `Promised` requests simply will fill-in the gaps as the application runs.

In that case, we don't really need the `async/await` pattern right? We just want to move forward with our loop and stones will fall in place behind us, whenever they are ready to fall in place (or not, in case of an error).

I would like to clarify this: `async/await` will just force things to run linearly, right? But if we do not want linearity, and we are ok with spawned tasks - `Promises` - to finish their thing in the background in some time when we are resuming with our run-cycle, we don't need that `async/await` pattern? Is that correct?

Comment: Right, don't forget handling errors in a `.catch` then, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `async`/`await` will just force things to run linearly, right?

Not globally, no. `await` makes the code in the `async` function it's used in wait for the promise you pass it to settle, but that only affects the function you use it in, not anything calling that function.

`async` functions are syntactic sugar for writing a function that returns a promise. `await` is syntactic sugar for consuming promises. Together, they dramatically simplify using promises (in particular by making rejections errors that automatically propagate through the call tree).

More specifically, an `async` function runs its code synchronously until the first `await` or `return` (or until code runs off the end of the function), at which point it returns a promise. Its logic then waits for the promise to settle, and continues; eventually it settles its promise based on what happened to the last promise it `await`ed or `return`ed (or fulfills it with `undefined` if code execution runs off the end).

If you don't want to wait for a promise to settle, you don't have to, not even in an `async` function. Just don't use `await` on it. For instance, assume we have this wrapper for `fetch` that gets JSON for us (and fixes the API footgun):

```
async function fetchJSON(...args) {
    const response = await fetch(...args);
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
    }
    return response.json();
}
```

Here's an `async` function using it that does an initial query to get a list of things to fetch, and then fetches all of those things in parallel::

```
async function fetchList(listUrl) {
    const list = await fetchJSON(listUrl);
    return Promise.all(list.map(item => fetchJSON(itemUrl)));
}
```

Notice how `fetchList` uses `await` to wait for the list of things to fetch, but then doesn't wait for the items; it just returns the promise from `Promise.all` for the list of items it starts fetching.

Also note how `await` within `fetchJSON` makes `fetchJSON`'s logic wait for the `fetch` promise to settle, but **doesn't** make the caller calling `fetchJSON` wait *unless that caller uses `await`*. `fetchList` only `await`s the first call (to get the list), it doesn't wait for the item from the list.

Comment: So the next stage in your example would be: `fetchList(['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']).then().catch()`?

Comment: @mbilyanov - Unless you were using it from an `async` function (or at the top level of a module once top-level `await` arrives), yes. :-)

Answer (score 2):

> I have been using Promises and async/await, they are pretty much the same thing right?

Well, `async/await` are helpful syntax built on top of promises.  `Async/await` relies on promises in order to work.  So, I wouldn't quite call them the same thing, but you can code identically functioning code with `await` surrounded by `try/catch` and `.then().catch()`.  You can use either.  Both methods rely on promises.

> However, I have recently encountered situations where my application does not care about waiting for the results to be fetched and the data containers to be updated etc. Let's say there is one larger loop that runs infinitely and any Promised requests simply will fill-in the gaps as the application runs.

> In that case, we don't really need the async/await pattern right? We just want to move forward with our loop and stones will fall in place behind us, whenever they are ready to fall in place (or not, in case of an error).

There is no rule that the caller has to pay attention to a returned promise or has to wait for it before going on with their task.  So, if you want to "just let the stones fall as they may in the background" as you say and that's appropriate for your application, you can code that way.

This is often referred to as "fire and forget" coding where you start some asynchronous operation that is going to do something on its own and you don't need to pay attention to when it finishes or if it had an error because that is of no consequence to the calling code.

But, there is a rule that you can't let a promise rejection go unhandled.  So, if you're returning a promise and the caller isn't going to do anything with it, then you have to make sure that any rejections are handled by the operation itself (with `.catch()`) so that the only thing that ever gets returned back is a resolved promise.  Even if all you do is notice the error and do nothing with it, you have to catch the error.

Comment: Yes, let's say, the caller isn't going to do anything with the outcome as you said. The process will update some `db` entry and if that fails, we switch some error flag somewhere but we have already moved forward in the run-time. So it is possible to say that it is ok to use the `.then().catch().finally()` pattern and we do not need the `async/await` pattern?

Comment: @mbilyanov - Sure, nobody ever said you had to use `async/await`.  We were programming with asynchronous operations just fine before `async/await` was implemented in the language.  Just make sure you catch all rejections.

Comment: "*There is no rule that the caller has to pay attention to a returned promise or has to wait for it before going on with their task.*" Just to illustrate this with an example - you might consider logging. When writing data on the disk, that should take time but you may not actually care to wait. So, you can do a log request that will be fulfilled later and you don't really want to stop and wait for this to complete. With a robust logging, you wouldn't expect a problem and if there *is* one, then maybe you're fine with it. There is likely something bigger that's wrong.

Comment: @VLAZ - Yes, that's a good example.  I sometimes also use fire and forget when closing a file.  If you get an error closing the file (particularly if just reading from the file), there's really nothing helpful you can do to recover other than log the error.